# Differention calculus help

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I don't know how to differentiate this function. $$u=\left(\frac{1}{t}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{t}}\right)^{2}$$

Should I use the quotient rule or just the power chain rule?

Comment: What is your question, what have you tried, and where are you stuck?

Comment: Yes I have tried sorry still trying to work out the bugs when posting math formulas on here but I'm confused on if I should use quotient rule or just the power chain rule.

Comment: So that your question isn't closed for being unclear, I added your comment (rephrasing it a bit) into the body of the question.

Comment: @FirstoLasto10 Check Dr MW's answer. Easy!

Answer (score 3):

Note that we can expand the term in parentheses to find

$$\begin{align}\frac{du}{dt}&=\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac1{t^2}-\frac{2}{t^{3/2}}+\frac{1}{t}\right)\\\\
&=-\frac{2}{t^3}+\frac{3}{t^{5/2}}-\frac{1}{t^2}
\end{align}$$

Alternatively, we can apply the chain rule to find

$$\begin{align}\frac{du}{dt}&=2\left(\frac1{t}-\frac{1}{t^{1/2}}\right)\left(-\frac1{t^2}+\frac{1}{2t^{3/2}}\right)\\\\&=-\frac{2}{t^3}+\frac{3}{t^{5/2}}-\frac{1}{t^2}
\end{align}$$

Comment: Instead of $x$ you mean $t$? Aren't you deriving w.r.t. $t$?

Comment: @imranfat Yes, thank you for catching the typo!

Comment: I originally used the chain rule but got confused and thought I was doing something wrong because textbook shows something different but thanks for the help

Comment: You're welcome!  It was my pleasure to help!  -Mark

Answer (score 0):

You want $\frac{du}{dt}$ so set $$p=\frac{1}{t}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{t}}$$ then $u=p^2$ and $\frac{du}{dt}=2p\frac{dp}{dt}$. Calculate $\frac{dp}{dt}$, put back with $p=\sqrt{u}$ and you will find the answer.